# Spring MVC: RequestMapping both class and method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

Is this possible?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String loginRoot() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/error", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginError() {
        return "login-error";
    }

}
```

I got a 404 error when accessing `localhost:8080/projectname/login` but not in `localhost:8080/projectname/login/error`.

Here's my web.xml
    project name

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-name>projectname</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>projectname</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't need the `/` in the method's mapping. Just map it to `""`.

Comment: And this will work because `""` will be relative to `"/login"` so still `/login`.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to "/" and you need to also add the request method.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginRoot() {
    return "login";
}
```

Consider using spring mvc tests to make the process of testing these scenarios easier:

https://spring.io/blog/2012/11/12/spring-framework-3-2-rc1-spring-mvc-test-framework

Comment: Just ran a quick test, in your case you can just have @RequestMapping and it will work. The request method is GET by default.

Comment: @BineshGunaratne The request method is not GET by default. If you omit the `method` attribute, all request methods will be matched.

Answer (score 6):

Yes that is possible. **The path in `@RequestMapping` on the method is relative to the path on the class annotation.**

With your current setup, `loginRoot()` will handle requests to

```
localhost:8080/projectname/login/
```

Assuming you don't have anything else in your configuration preventing this.

Comment: that's what I believe too but Im getting a 404 error accessing `localhost:8080/projectname/login` and I dont know why, did I miss something?

Comment: Do you have a JSP named "login.jsp" in the same directory as your "error.jsp"?

Comment: @orvyl It works for me. Can we see your web.xml and servlet context configuration? Your mappings are probably different and preventing this.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What Spring version are you using? I just ran into a very similar issue with 4.0.0.RELEASE, and using an empty mapping string fixed it. Note that the question doesn't have the trailing slash on the URL, and yours does.

Comment: @chrylis I'm on 4.0.2. This behavior has existed since at least 3.1, iirc. I'm suggesting they change from using `/login` to using `/login/` for the request to reach the handler. Again, this might be an issue with the rest of the configuration.

Comment: Ow! Im sorry, adding `/` at the end of the url fixed the error. So, when someone want to have a url without `/` at the last of url, set `@RequestMapping("")` instead of `@RequestMapping("/")`

Comment: @orvyl That's it. You actually don't need to add a value at all, just `@RequestMapping`, with any other attributes.